# Plsql to spell number (currency) to Italian currency without hardcoded the translation number

Tags: oracle, plsql, currency

I could not find a post to do it automatically as I don't want to hard coded the mapping between English to Italian.

Is there any way to write the spelling number to any language in PLSQL, Oracle 10g or 11i ?

I do not have this built in package: AP_AMOUNT_UTILITIES_PKG in my oracle.

Comment: I woudn't do it in SQL, to be honest. Are you using a database in a web application? If so, I'd do it in your framework.

Comment: It's a native SQL that require to select only from the DB and output it in Italian ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Currency_conversion(currency IN NUMBER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
    txt varchar2(4000);
    tlum  varchar2(4000);
    babelTxt varchar(32000);
    req   utl_http.req;
    resp  utl_http.resp;
    webtext VARCHAR2(4000);
    webextract VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    -- This is used to convert number to words in english
    SELECT CAST( to_char( to_timestamp( lpad(currency,9,'0'), 'FF9' ), 'FFSP' ) AS VARCHAR2(100) )
    into txt from dual;

    -- FFSP is used to spell Fraction second in words for example HH24SP
    -- can be used to spell hours from 0 to 23,i used FFSP to get max range
    txt:=translate(txt,'x-','x ');

    -- The below logic is taken from
    -- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1122273(and)start=15(and)    tstart=0
    --need to test once
    -- request that exceptions are raised for error status codes
    utl_http.set_response_error_check(enable => TRUE); 
    -- allow testing for exceptions like Utl_Http.Http_Server_Error
    utl_http.set_detailed_excp_support(enable => TRUE);

    txt:=utl_url.escape(txt);

    babelTxt := 'http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt?doit=done' || '&'   || 'lp=en_it' || '&' || 'intl=1' || '&' || 'ei=utf8' || '&' || 'trtext=' || txt;
    req:=utl_http.begin_request(url => babelTxt, method => 'GET');
    resp := utl_http.get_response(r => req);
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            --utl_http.read_text(r => resp, data => webtext, len => 32767);
                utl_http.read_line(r => resp , data => webtext);

            webextract := regexp_substr(webtext,'<div id="result"><div style="padding:0.6em;">(.+)</div></div>');

            if webextract is not null 
            then
                select regexp_replace(webextract,'<div id="result"><div style="padding:0.6em;">(.+)</div></div>','\1')        
                into tlum FROM dual;
            end if;

            exit when tlum is not null;

            END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
     NULL;
    END;



    utl_http.end_response(r => resp);

    return tlum;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
        return '';
END;
/
exit;
```

Comment: When I install, the script ask some variable:
:START
:TSTART
:LP
:INTL
:EI
:TRTEXT
What should we put for them?

Comment: The issue is with & as plsql consider it as input variable

Comment: I escape the & by using concatenate string to each & to other text for the URL:
<code>select regexp_replace(regexp_substr(httpuritype ('http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt?doit=done' || '&' || 'lp=en_it' || '&' || 'intl=1' || '&' || 'ei=utf8' || '&' || 'trtext=' || txt.getclob(),
        '<div id="result"><div style="padding:0.6em;">(.+)</div></div>'),
        '<div id="result"><div style="padding:0.6em;">(.+)</div></div>', '\1') 
into tlum FROM dual;</code>
but still error (1. missing right parenthesis, 2. error syntax of httpuritype) ~ please help

Comment: I called it in select request: 
select Currency_conversion(1234000)  from dual;

It wont display the result since the babelfish has a big html string

Comment: After I corrected above sql, I can't get the translated text from babelfish now because of the sql can't get the full html text and extract: <div id="result"><div style="padding:0.6em;">(.+)</div></div> ~ I got blank result

Comment: Try now i have corrected the code The regexp_substr is used to get the matching string <div id="result"><div style="padding:0.6em;">UN MILIONE DI DUECENTO TRENTAQUATTRO MILA</div></div>
and then the next regexp_replace would get UN MILIONE DI DUECENTO TRENTAQUATTRO MILA

Comment: Thanks for keeping help me, I still got blank, for me the issue with **utl_http.request** which we could retrieve the full HTML text but the plsql could not got all the text, I tested the request in sql, I could see the last extracted text: **a.button:visited {** and the total string could be around 3000 characters only. It won't reach to the tag: **<div id="result"><div style="padding:0.6em;">** so that we can't extract the result and got blank. Any other way to get full HTML text from the request?

Comment: Hi Mtr i had made changes to the function to get the data ,even then if u are not able to get then just let me know ,one more suggestion once you retrieve the currency value store it in a table so that u dont need to again get the webpage for the same value

Comment: Thanks, after this, I got error: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested, so I edited the function as shown above and got the result now. 
Tested:

**SQL> select Currency_conversion(1234000)  from dual;**
**UN MILIONE DI DUECENTO TRENTAQUATTRO MILA**

. Many Thanks

Comment: This is a clever solution but suffers from its reliance on the external Babelfish translator.  This means it can only be used int databases which have a direct connection to the internet.  Additionally in 11g you will need to set an ACL policy to allow the connections.

Comment: So personally I would use Babelfish to produce the list of Italian numbers (as you don't speak Italian) and then feed that  list into the functions available on the Ask Tom thread to which Rob linked.

Comment: @APC interesting solution on translation, I'm on waiting my client to accept my request to use above function but of course, felt no success since we might no be able to allow external connection, I want to translate it to a table but I don't know any grammar of Italian, can we open a solution for such translation?